# Ruby issue about calling a method

Tags: ruby

In Ruby what is the difference calling method from the same file but outside the class and calling the same method outside the class from different file.

I added require 'inifile' to my code

first case it worked properly and load the data in the hash but in the second case it gives the following error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/inifile-3.0.0/lib/inifile.rb:98:in `initialize': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/inifile-3.0.0/lib/inifile.rb:98:in `open'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/inifile-3.0.0/lib/inifile.rb:98:in `write'
    from LoadConfig.rb:5:in `<class:LoadConfig>'
    from LoadConfig.rb:2:in `<main>
```

this is function body

def write( opts = {} )
    filename = opts.fetch(:filename, @filename)

```
encoding = opts.fetch(:encoding, @encoding)
mode = encoding ? "w:#{encoding}" : "w"

File.open(filename, mode) do |f|
  @ini.each do |section,hash|

    f.puts "[#{section}]"
    hash.each {|param,val| f.puts "#{param} #{@param} #{escape_value val}"}
    f.puts
  end
end
```

and this is how I am calling write function

```
obj = IniFile.new
obj.write()
```

Comment: I couldn't get what kind code you wrote. Could you write the code? The error indicate that you didn't set the filename.

Comment: You can pass encoding in as a separate option rather than having to mangle it into a string: `File.open(filename, mode: 'w', encoding: encoding)`.